# How is cartilage immunised?

Tags: human-biology, immunity, lymphatic-system, cartilage

How is human cartilage immunised (protected) against pathogens since it does not contain lymphatic vessels?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this relevant problem, when I was learning about cartilage tissue.

Generally, cartilage tissue has no blood supply. But it is a traversable  tissue, therefore nutrients, and breathing gases can enter into the tissue without any problem.

But the problem is how does it immunized while there is not containing of lymphatic cells.

The perichondrium, has a presence  of blood vessels. It pulls/stimulate  the necessaries for enter to the cartlage tissue. That's how, the  tissue get immunized.

[image]